# integrity error: UNIQUE constraint failed: dating_app_uservote.user_id, dating_app_uservote.voter_id Django

Tags: django

Not sure what's going wrong here. IF two users have both voted yes to each other, hence both having a vote attribute of True, I am attempting to add both of them to my matches database. But it's not working and I'm not clear why. Looked around a bit at other similar posts, still stuck.

**error **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/views.py", line 148, in nope
    return create_vote(request, profile_id, False)
  File "/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/views.py", line 159, in create_vote
    vote=vote
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1335, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: dating_app_uservote.user_id, dating_app_uservote.voter_id
```

**views.py/create_vote**

```
def create_vote(request, profile_id, vote):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    UserVote.objects.create(
        user=profile,
        voter=request.user,
        vote=vote
    )
    if vote:
        if UserVote.objects.filter(
            user = request.user,
            voter=profile,
            vote=True
        ).count():
            npm = Profile.objects.get(request.user)
            npm.matches.add(User.objects.get(username=profile.username))

            npm = Profile.objects.get(user=profile)
            npm.matches.add(User.objects.get(username=request.user))

            npm.save()
            return render(request, 'dating_app/matches.html', dict(
                match=profile,
            ))
    return redirect('dating_app:mingle')
```

**models.py**

```
class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))
```

**mingle.html**

```
{% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}


{% block content %}
<div class="tindero">
    {% if profile %}
        <div class="container content is-child box column is-4 is-offset-4">
            <img src="{{ profile.photo.url  }}" width="300">
            <p style="font-size: 25px">{{profile.username}}</p>

            <b>Bio:</b>
            <p>{{profile.description}}</p>
            <div class="columns has-text-centered">
                <div class="column is-half">
                    <a href="{% url 'dating_app:nope' profile.id %}" class="button is-danger" style="width: 100%"> Dislike </a>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="{% url 'dating_app:nice' profile.id %}" class="button is-primary" style="width: 100%"> Like </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    {% else %}
        <br><br>
        <p>Wait for more people to join!</p>
        <p>Help us get more user. Share this link to your friends! <a href="http://localhost:8000/">http://localhost:8000/</a></p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**all of views.py**

```
def home(request):

    return render(request, 'dating_app/home.html')


def profiles(request):
    "Shows a list of profiles that have been created"
    profiles = Profile.objects.order_by('date_joined')
    context = {'profiles' : profiles}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/profiles.html',context)


def profile(request, profile_id):
    """show a single profile"""
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)
    context = {'profile' : profile}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/profile.html', context)



# Below is related to users


def logout_view(request):
    """Log out the user """
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dating_app:home'))


def register(request, profile_id):
    user =User.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    user.profile.bio = 'fjfjfjjf'
    user.save()


def register(request):
    #Register a new user
    context = {}

    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            description = form.cleaned_data.get("description")
            photo = form.cleaned_data.get("photo")
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            profile = authenticate(username=username,email=email,description=description, photo=photo, password=raw_password)
            login(request, profile)
            return redirect ('dating_app:home')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    else: #get request 
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'dating_app/register.html', context)



def update_account(request, profile_id):
    #Edit an existing profile 
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)
    update_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        #Initial request; prefil form with current entry
        update_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile)
    else:
        #POST data submitted;process data. 
        update_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if update_form.is_valid():
            update_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dating_app:profile', args=[profile.id]))

    context = {'profile' : profile, 'update_form' : update_form}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/update.html', context)



#matching
def mingle(request):



    try:
        profile = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])
    except IndexError:
        profile = None
        print(Profile.username)
    try:

        description = request.user.description
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        create = Profile.objects.get_or_create(request.user)
        return redirect('profile')

    match = request.user.matches.all()
    context = dict(profile = profile, match = match)    
    return render(request, 'dating_app/mingle.html', context)


def create_vote(request, profile_id, vote):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    UserVote.objects.create(
        user = profile,
        voter = request.user,
        vote = vote
    )
    return redirect('dating_app:mingle')





def nice(request, profile_id):
    return create_vote(request, profile_id, True)


def nope(request, profile_id):
    return create_vote(request, profile_id, False)





def create_vote(request, profile_id, vote):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    UserVote.objects.create(
        user=profile,
        voter=request.user,
        vote=vote
    )
    if vote:
        if UserVote.objects.filter(
            user = request.user,
            voter=profile,
            vote=True
        ).count():
            npm = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            npm.matches.add(User.objects.get(username=profile.username))

            npm = Profile.objects.get(user=profile)
            npm.matches.add(User.objects.get(username=request.user))

            npm.save()
            return render(request, 'dating_app/matches.html', dict(
                match=profile,
            ))
    return redirect('dating_app:mingle')


def view_matches(request,profile_id):
    match = request.user.matches.all()
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)

    context = {'match' : match, 'profile' : profile}

    return render(request, 'dating_app/matches.html', context)
```

Comment: It's better to include the traceback from your logs not the error message page from Django

Comment: @IainShelvington Got it. Just put it up!

Comment: You’re creating a UserVote without checking of one exists already in create_vote

Comment: @IainShelvington Hmmm...  I played around with it, and now I'm getting 'profile object is not iterable' for npm = Profile.objects.get(request.user)

Comment: `Profile.objects.get` (the .get) specifically is not iterable because it returns one item not a queryset.  If you changed it to `.filter()` it would get rid of the error, but `.filter()` may not be what you want if you are trying to get one object.  `.filter()` has the potential of returning more than one.

Comment: @ja408 Well, I keep getting different errors even if I don't change it. Now I'm dealing with 'Exception Value: 
UserVote matching query does not exist.' at     return create_vote(request, profile_id, True)  and vote=vote